# Cannot find all SpecFlow Options in Add New Item in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: specflow, visual-studio-2022

I am using SpecFlow in Visual Studio 2022. I have installed SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2022 extension. But I cannot find all SpecFlow templates when I want to Add New Item. I can find only three of them.[image: SpecFlow Templates for Visual Studio 2022]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not there, because we didn't implement them for Visual Studio 2022.

This issue is https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.VS/issues/73

We are happy to add additional ones, but nobody yet answered me which of the missing ones you need.

Comment: Thanks for informing, I thought I made some mistakes in setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link down from Microsoft !

I close my visual studio 2022 » then install that

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowForVisualStudio2022

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).